# How to use multiple conditions in asp.net Eval function to enable and disable a button in a templatefield?

Tags: asp.net, eval, bind, enable-if

Please Help.
I want to enable and disable the select button conditionally on question type

my code is

```
<ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Button ID="btn_EditSurveyQuestion" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Edit" Text="Edit" />
        &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="btn_ViewSurveyQuestion" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Select" Text="Select" Enabled='<%# Eval("QuestionType").ToString()!="long text" ? true:false%>' '<%# Eval("QuestionType").ToString()!="short text" ? true:false   %>' />
        &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="btn_DeleteSurveyQuestion" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Delete" Text="Delete" />
</ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just chain your conditions:

```
Enabled='<%# Eval("QuestionType").ToString()!="long text" ? true: Eval("QuestionType").ToString()!="short text" ? true : false%>'
```

EDIT: Another way is to just add a method to the code behind of the form and bind to that:

```
Public Function EnableViewSurveyQuestion(questionType As String) As Boolean

    Return questionType = "long text" OrElse questionType = "short text"

End Function
```

Then in the markup:

```
Enabled='<%# EnableViewSurveyQuestion(Eval("QuestionType").ToString()) %>'
```

Comment: Would you please tell me if there is another solution for this problem?